# Nginx is not working in CentOS?

Tags: nginx, centos7

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
[root@localhost bin]# nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
[root@localhost bin]# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: **failed** (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-04-09 16:35:28 IST; 6min ago
  Process: 22654 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (**code=exited, status=1/FAILURE**)
  Process: 22597 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22595 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 09 16:35:27 localhost.localdomain nginx[22654]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Apr 09 16:35:27 localhost.localdomain nginx[22654]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Apr 09 16:35:28 localhost.localdomain nginx[22654]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Apr 09 16:35:28 localhost.localdomain nginx[22654]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Apr 09 16:35:28 localhost.localdomain nginx[22654]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Apr 09 16:35:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 09 16:35:28 localhost.localdomain nginx[22654]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Apr 09 16:35:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: **Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.**
Apr 09 16:35:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Apr 09 16:35:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

> Error:  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-04-09 16:35:28 IST;
>           Process: 22654 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>           Apr 09 16:35:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.

Comment: `bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)` means that another process (another `nginx` instance or another program) is using port 80 already. `sudo netstat -tupln` tells you which one.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should ask such questions at the appropriate place (for example, superuser.com or serverfault.com).

Answer (score 3):

The error basically means that some other application is using those default ports. You can check that using :

`sudo netstat -tulpn`

Get the PID of the process that already using that port and send signal with kill command.

`sudo kill -2 <PID>`
`sudo service nginx restart`

In my case apache httpd was running on the same port and I didn't want to kill that process so I changed the default port for nginx to some other port. This is how my `nginx.conf` looks now.

```
server {
    listen       3000 default_server;
    listen       [::]:3000 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Also, make sure that in this file, `user` is set as the user you are logged in as ( for ex `root` ).

If this is not the case, you can try other options mentioned [here.](https://chrisjean.com/fix-nginx-emerg-bind-to-80-failed-98-address-already-in-use/)

You can use `nginx -t` to test that the file `nginx.conf` is in correct syntax.